# Secure way to compare two secret numbers without disclosing them?

Tags: algorithm-design

For example, two people want to know who is the older, without disclosing their age. Is there a secure way to do this without a third party involved?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course there are ways to do that.

See for example, [Secure Integer Comparison with Applications in Economics](http://www.daimi.au.dk/~ttoft/publications/progress.pdf) which is implemented in [VIFF](http://viff.dk).

Also, solutions to the [millionaire's problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yao%27s_Millionaires%27_Problem) would probably do the trick too. There are lots of these. Just search around for solutions to that problem.